# How can set New Security Credential for ldap Authentication in Java Code

Tags: java, security, authentication, ldap, credentials

Hashtable env = new Hashtable(11);`create environment`
     env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
             "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
     env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:10389/ou=system");`url Declaration`
     env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "secret");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
         env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "ou=121,ousystem");`For this is Domain`
         env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "secret");`set new credential`
     // Search and retrieve DN.

```
     DirContext ctx = null;
    NamingEnumeration results = null;
    try {
        ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);`cant create obj here`
        SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
     // Authenticate
          ldap = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
           } catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
     ae.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NamingException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Error : javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:`when creating obj for context`

Answer (score 2):

Your Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL seems to be incorrect , it can't be an OU (Org Unit) but a CN , UID , etc. In your case it can be cn=121,ou=ousystem. You need to check it out.

If you have an LDAP Browser  ,say Apache Directory Studio or Softera LDAP , try connecting to your LDAP server with the connection details.